# Redirect /search?query=foo to /search/foo

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect `/search?query=foo` to `/search/foo` but all my attempts have failed.

I have tried the solutions in similar questions but they have not worked. I believe this is because I am trying to rewrite the request to `index.php` so that the PHP framework can process it.

I know that it is not the PHP framework causing the issue as when I manually go to `/search/foo` it is handled correctly.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ search/%1 [R=302,NS]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I don't understand why it's not working as when I look at the logs the URL is successfully being transformed into what I'm after:

```
applying pattern '^' to uri 'search'
RewriteCond: input='/search' pattern='^/search$' => matched
RewriteCond: input='query=asd' pattern='^query=(.*)$' => matched
rewrite 'search' -> 'search/asd'
add per-dir prefix: search/asd -> .../app/public/search/asd
explicitly forcing redirect with http://localhost/.../app/public/search/asd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the query string. Instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ search/%1 [R=302,NS]
```

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+search\?query=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [L,R=302,NS]
```

The important part is the `?` after the backreference, `%1`. This tells mod_rewrite that the *new* query string is just `?` (i.e. nothing). Othewise the existing query string automatically gets appended to the rewritten URL/redirect.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestions on my original pattern (out of curiosity) and it works when I added the `?` and `L` condition. Does your condition offer advantages over mine?

Comment: As a side note for anyone using this solution, I also had to add `RewriteBase /` to stop `mod_rewrite` from appending the absolute path after `localhost`.

Comment: @maddisoj only difference is the it checks the actual request instead of the uri, just a precaution to precent internal looping